# Multiple JQuery validation applied to only single textbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am writing extended method to apply regular expression validation to different textboxes.

**HTML**

```
<form class="getintouch_form" name="Form_ContactUs" action="" id="frm">
  <div class="getintouchform_field">
    <label class="inputform_label">Your Name*</label>
    <input class="inputform_textfld" type="text" placeholder="John Smith" maxlength="50" name="Name" id="TxtName" />
  </div>
  <div class="getintouchform_field">
    <label class="inputform_label">Your Email Address*</label>
    <input class="inputform_textfld" type="text" placeholder="john@thiscompany.com" name="Email" id="TxtEmailId" />
  </div>
  <div class="getintouchform_field">
    <label class="inputform_label">Best number to call you back on*</label>
    <input class="inputform_textfld" type="text" placeholder="Telephone or Cell number" name="ContactNumber" id="TxtContactNumber" />
  </div>
  <div class="getintouchform_field">
    <label class="inputform_label">Company Name*</label>
    <input class="inputform_textfld" type="text" placeholder="Company Name" name="CompanyName" id="TxtCompanyName" />
  </div>
  <div class="getintouchform_field">
    <label class="inputform_label">Role in an Organization*</label>
    <input class="inputform_textfld" type="text" placeholder="Role in an Organization" name="Role" id="TxtRole" />
  </div>
  <div class="getintouchform_field">
    <label class="inputform_label">Optional Message</label>
    <textarea class="inputform_textarea" placeholder="Type your message here..." id="OptionalMessage"></textarea>
  </div>
  <button class="submitbtn bluebutton" id="BtnSend" type="button">send</button>
</form>
```

**Jquery**

```
var _form = $("#frm");

$.validator.addMethod(
  "Email",
  function(value, element) {
    return /^([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z.]{2,5})$/i.test(value);
  },
  "Please enter a valid email address."
);

$.validator.addMethod(
  "Name",
  function(value, element) {
    return /^[a-zA-Z]+([a-zA-Z ]+)*$/i.test(value);
  },
  "Please enter a valid Name."
);

$.validator.addMethod(
  "ContactNumber",
  function(value, element) {
    return /^[A-Z0-9 _]*[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9 _]*$/i.test(value);
  },
  "Please enter a valid ContactNumber."
);

_form.validate({
  onfocusout: function(element) {
    $(element).valid();
  },
  rules: {
    Name: {
      required: true
    },
    Email: {
      required: true
      //email: true
    },
    ContactNumber: {
      required: true,
      maxlength: 15
    },

    CompanyName: {
      required: true
    },
    Role: {
      required: true
    }
  },

  messages: {
    Name: {
      required: "Name is mandatory field."
    },
    ContactNumber: {
      required: "Contact Number is mandatory field. ",
      maxlength: "Invalid Contact Number.",
      phoneUS: "Invalid Contact Number."
    },
    Email: {
      required: "Email is mandatory field."
    },
    CompanyName: {
      required: "Company Name is mandatory field."
    },
    Role: {
      required: "Role In Organization is mandatory field."
    }
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    _insertData();
  }
});
```

My issue is Name validation is applied to all the textboxes. I've attached screenshot :
[image]

CodePen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ybwvwv

Comment: I suspect it's because all the inputs have `name="something"`, and it's matching that attribute to the validation method.

Comment: But as you can see, all textboxes have different name value

Comment: you can check codepen as well

Comment: I know the name values are different. I think it's matching the attribute name, not the values. It's the same way that it automatically recognizes the `required` attribute as being equivalent to using `required:` in the rules.

Comment: Any solution? suggestion?

Comment: Change `name="Name"` to something like `name="Fullname"` and change the validation method similarly.

Comment: If I change name attributes, all regular expression stops working. Strange

Comment: Not if you change `$.validator.addMethod(
  "Name",` to `$.validator.addMethod(
  "Fullname",`

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zwbRxE check this

Comment: I'm not seeing any validation messages in your codepen. But I think `name="fullName"` needs to be `name="FullNameField"` to match the validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.addClassRules()](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addClassRules/) after [.addMethod()](https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/) to connect rule to CSS class then add the classes to input fields.

```
$.validator.addClassRules({
    Email : { Email : true },
    FullNameField : { FullNameField : true},
    ContactNumber : { ContactNumber : true}, 
});
```

Then add the class to input field:

```
<input class="inputform_textfld Email" type="text" placeholder="john@thiscompany.com" name="Email" id="TxtEmailId" />
<input class="inputform_textfld ContactNumber" type="text" placeholder="Telephone or Cell number" name="ContactNumber" id="TxtContactNumber" />
<input class="inputform_textfld CompanyName" type="text" placeholder="Company Name" name="CompanyName" id="TxtCompanyName" />
```

[**Updated CodePEN**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xdBjVE)

also as [sparky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/594235/sparky) said:

> There is no reason to attach a single rule to a class name. By
>   default, the name of the rule can already be used as the class name.
>   In other words, you do not need .addClassRules() to do class="Email";
>   it will work exactly the same. The only point of .addClassRules() is
>   to make a "compound" rule by assigning several rules to a single class
>   name.

so you need just to add the classes without `addClassRules`

Comment: There is no reason to attach a single rule to a class name.  By default, the name of the rule can already be used as the class name.  In other words, you do not need `.addClassRules()` to do `class="Email"`; it will work exactly the same.  The only point of `.addClassRules()` is to make a *"compound"* rule by assigning several rules to a single class name.

Comment: @Sparky Thank you for explaining that, I've added your comment to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Finally with the help of [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) and some research on internet, I solved it by changing name attribute like this:

Name -> FullName
Email -> UserEmail

Here is my final code:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
  "UserEmail",
  function(value, element) {
    return /^([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z.]{2,5})$/i.test(value);
  },
  "Please enter a valid email address."
);

$.validator.addMethod(
  "FullName",
  function(value, element) {
    return /^[a-zA-Z]+([a-zA-Z ]+)*$/i.test(value);
  },
  "Please enter a valid Name."
);

$.validator.addMethod(
  "ContactNumber",
  function(value, element) {
    return /^[A-Z0-9 _]*[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9 _]*$/i.test(value);
  },
  "Please enter a valid ContactNumber."
);
```

And In validation Rule, I checked additional method like this:

```
rules: {
    FullName: {
      required: true,
      FullName: true
    },
    UserEmail: {
      required: true
      UserEmail: true,
    },
    ContactNumber: {
      required: true,
      maxlength: 15,
      ContactNumber : true,
    },

    CompanyName: {
      required: true
    },
    Role: {
      required: true
    }
  }
```

Finally it works. Thanks for helping all.